# How to stop onload play html5 video on websites?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video, internet-explorer, html

Anyone know how stop automatic play on page load unwanted html5 videos?
This is importnant for me because I use limited bandwith transfer, and that unwanted media eat my amount of limited transfer.
Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/227669/how-to-stop-auto-playing-html5-videos-in-your-web-browser/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Enter `about:config` into Firefox’s address bar and press Enter.
- Agree to the warning.
- Type `autoplay` into the search box.
- You’ll see a preference named `media.autoplay.enabled`, which will be set to `True`.
- Double-click that preference and it will change to `False`.

Be warned that animated GIF loads normally, but doesn't play. Many times you're not aware of this, and just see an image and think that's it. This happens to me on Reddit a lot. Then you have to right-click the image and select `Play`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, that is really helpful especially that hint with gif's loading in background.

Comment: As you're new on Superuser, if you find this answer helpful, you may upvote it, and if it answers your question, you can accept it.

Comment: accepted - done!

Comment: "Be warned that animated GIF loads normally, but doesn't play", false. The GIFs aren't stopped, example here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif