# Disable autoplay of BBC videos

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video, browser, browser-plugin

In the UK the BBC News website (and many others of course) have dropped Flash and use HTML5 to play videos. Unfortunately they also use a continuous-play plugin which can not be disabled, only turned off for the moment.

How can I disable this continuous-play plugin?

Comment: This site isn't a request forum. Please see the help pages to understand how to ask a useful question.

Comment: For Firefox, possible duplicate of [How to stop onload play html5 video on websites?](https://superuser.com/questions/1128764/how-to-stop-onload-play-html5-video-on-websites).

Answer (score 1):

## Chrome

Click Chrome’s menu button and select Settings to open the Settings page. Click Show advanced settings, click Content settings under Privacy, scroll down to Plug-ins, and select Click to play.

## Firefox

Tools -> Addons -> Plugins and changing the drop-down to Ask to Activate.

https://www.howtogeek.com/188059/how-to-enable-click-to-play-plugins-in-every-web-browser/

Comment: Sadly this no longer works in Chrome, because most sites use HTML5 video which is not a plugin.

Comment: Try going to chrome://flags and setting "Autoplay Policy" to "Document user activation is required"